# ¿Cuándo proteger preguntas?

Tags: discusión, privilegios

En muchos sitos de [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) he visto preguntas protegidas y aquí ninguna (que yo recuerde).

Hace poco conseguí el privilegio de poder proteger, pero **¿Cuándo debería hacerlo?**

Según los [privilegios,](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) las preguntas que pueden ser protegidas son:

> Cualquier pregunta con al menos un día de antigüedad puede ser puede ser protegida y desprotegida por los usuarios que tengan este privilegio, siempre que la pregunta haya obtenido al menos una respuesta de un usuario con menos de 10 puntos de reputación (estos usuarios no podrán publicar más respuestas una vez que la pregunta haya sido protegida).

Y a parte de el *cuándo* está el, ¿por qué no hay más preguntas protegidas?

Comment: Talvés nunca llegue a hacer uso de este privilegio :P y menos ahora que con la graduación cambiarán :D

Comment: @Flxtr na, lo lograrás ^^ Ahora puedes, rapido antes de que te lo quiten xD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> En muchos sitos de [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) he visto preguntas protegidas y aquí ninguna (que yo recuerde).

Sí hay preguntas protegidas. Ahora mismo, 40. Las puedes ver en la [Lista de preguntas protegidas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/protected-questions).

> Hace poco conseguí el privilegio de poder proteger, pero **¿Cuándo debería hacerlo?**

De [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/209901) en la sección FAQ de Meta Stack Exchange:

> ### ¿Cuándo debería proteger o desproteger una pregunta?
>
> - Protege preguntas que atraen muchas no-respuestas o respuestas de baja calidad (spam, etc.) de nuevos usuarios.
> - No protejas preguntas solamente porque están en páginas de noticias con muchas visitas.
> - Desprotege preguntas que actualmente no estén atrayendo demasiada atención y que históricamente no tengan demasiadas respuestas poco útiles.

Una pregunta protegida tiene el mensaje:

> Esta pregunta está protegida para evitar respuestas tipo "gracias!", "¡Yo también!", o spam de los nuevos usuarios. Para responder a ello, usted debe haber ganado al menos 10 [reputation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) en este sitio [el bono asociación no cuenta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)).

Por lo que subir el umbral a 10 puntos evita que puedan responder los usuarios no registrados o sin reputación acumulada.

Por ejemplo, [Virtual Box no inicia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22698/83) está protegida y [la marcó así](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/22698/timeline) el usuario Comunidad después de que recibiera tres respuestas marcadas como no útiles.

---

En general, considero normal que haya pocas preguntas protegidas actualmente, básicamente porque **no es necesario aún**. Las respuestas "malas" suelen florecer en preguntas con muchas visitas, que la gente encuentra en Google y en las que decide aportar una respuesta sin tener en cuenta las reglas del sitio. Actualmente Stack Overflow en español es un sitio bastante nuevo y sin demasiado buen SEO, como muestra que haya apenas 14 preguntas con la medalla [Pregunta famosa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) que se da al recibir 10.000 visitas (y [la que más](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/5390/83) no llega a las 25.000).

A medida que tengamos preguntas que atraigan más y más visitas, veremos como pasa a ser necesario.

Comment: Gracias! no conocia el enlace de "tools" que pasaste. Pero sigo sin tener claro por qué hay tan pocas protegidas... además la actividad de usuarios nuevos con repsuestas de baja calidad y demás, pasa en el momento de publicacion, no pasado un dia :/

Comment: @lois6b añadí una interpretación final. Básicamente, creo que aún no ha hecho demasiada falta: no atraemos hordas de visitantes, por lo que tampoco tenemos multitud de respuestas malas.

Comment: Si, supongo que la falta de *popularidad* en la red hace que no sea necesario proteger.. gracias de nuevo ^^